# Inconsistent behavior in Python when using a property decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Here's a simple file depicting some inconsistent Python (3.6) behavior. Why is it possible that `Case 1` and `Case 2` run but `Case 3` fails, even though `Case 3` is just a merger of the first two cases?

I have provided the `dis` output of the first two cases.

```
import dis # Python bytecode disassembler

class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.x # In case 2 (and 3), getting x results in a function call (because they are @properties), which fails when instantiating A because y is undefined. Case 1 evaluates the reference to a function without calling it and so it does not raise an exception.

  # CASE 1: Legal
  def x(self):
    y
    pass

  '''
  # CASE 2: Legal
  @property
  def x(self):
    pass
  '''

  '''
  # CASE 3: Illegal:
  @property
  def x(self):
    y
    pass
  '''

if __name__ == '__main__':
  a = A()
  dis.dis(A)
```

**Case 1 bytecode:**

```
Disassembly of __init__:
  5           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              2 LOAD_ATTR                0 (x)
              4 POP_TOP
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of x:
  9           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (y)
              2 POP_TOP

 10           4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

**Case 2 bytecode:**

```
Disassembly of __init__:
  5           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              2 LOAD_ATTR                0 (x)
              4 POP_TOP
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: In case 1, you aren't calling anything; `self.x` is a function reference that isn't used. In case 3, `self.x` actually calls the defined getter for `x`, which presumably is then trying to access an undefined global name.

Comment: In other words, your comment "getting x results in a function call" is incorrect. It evaluates to a function object, which you neglect to call.

Comment: That commented line wasn't supposed to make it into this post. If I'm not mistaken, I think that line applies if case 2 were uncommented and the others were commented out.

Comment: @chepner, got it, thanks! When I ran a.x() with case 1, I got the same error as in case 3. I hadn't realized that using [at]property would result in a call to the x method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @chepner's comment:

> In case 1, you aren't calling anything; self.x is a function reference
>   that isn't used. In case 3, self.x actually calls the defined getter
>   for x, which presumably is then trying to access an undefined global
>   name.

The behavior caused by the line `self.x` in case 3 is fundamentally different from case 1 because case 1 doesn't call anything -- it just evaluates a reference to a function.

On the other hand, `self.x` in case 3 executes the body of the `x` method, resulting in the undefined `y` error.

In order to confirm @chepner's comment, I ran a.x() with case 1 and got the same error as in case 3.

Answer (score 1):

There is no inconsistency here.

When you instantiate `a = A()`, `__init__` is called, which calls `self.x`, which will execute the body of `x`. At that point, there is no `y` inscope, so you get an exception.

Comment: Sorry, what is the confusion? And this should probably be a comment, not an answer...

Comment: I'm confused because I don't understand what is inconsistent about the poster's code? I've edited the answer.